# How to implement the photo stack view?

Tags: android, view, customization

I must to implement the photo stack view. 
User can see the top image and can remove the top image by swiping out screen. 
The photo stack view will be like the below image. 
Please give me your recommend or a library to help me to do it 
Thanks a lot. 
[image: photo stack]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leo Nguyen Hey..you can do that with the stack view layout. You can try looking at the android samples for the basic stack view example that has the changing text instead of photo.  I am trying to do the similar stuff but stuck with pictures. Did you find a way out?